# Whats the use of <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Tags: html, character-encoding, content-type, meta

Is it still necessary/beneficial to use the following ancient meta tag in the head, or is it obsolete? What purpose does this sentence offer and it safe to remove it?

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

I already have `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in my .htaccess file; `<!doctype html>` on the top of my webpage and `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in the head of my php generated html webpage [index.php]

I need full mobile/desktop coverage for the major browsers like IE9+, FireFox20+, Edge, Chrome, Safari, etc for browsers on pc mac linux android and iphones of say at most 5 years old, today and the future. Thanks

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/doctype-mirror/wikis/MetaCharsetAttribute.wiki

In theory `<meta charset="utf-8">` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` are the same.

But honestly, I won't take any risk if your project must work in IE

Comment: The generally accepted reason is that if the user saves the web page and then loads it later, the http headers will no longer be available, so without the meta tag, the browser will not know what character encoding to use.